# In iphone safari and chrome brower z-index is not working. background overlapping issue in side navbar

Tags: html, jquery, css, angular

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2eFe.jpg)

In my project I am facing a issue only on IOS mobile content of the page is overlapping over my navsidebar but working perfectly fine on other devices.

You can check the live url of my site below:

https://webapp.world

Attached CSS and Html code of my angular project for your reference

Thanks in advance.

.

```
.pushNav {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #2e2f35;
  transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
}

.pushNav hr {
  border: 1px solid #555;
}

.pushNav,
.pushNav a {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: helvetica, sens-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pushNavIsOpen {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.js-topPushNav.isOpen,
.pushNav_level.isOpen {
  right: 0;
}

.closeLevel,
.openLevel {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.openLevel,
.closeLevel,
.pushNav a {
  padding: 1em 1em;
  display: block;
  text-indent: 5px;
  transition: background 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.openLevel:hover,
.closeLevel:hover,
.pushNav a:hover {
  background: #494a50;
}

.openLevel span {
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.hdg {
  background-color: #1e1e24;
}

.closeLevel,
closelevel > i {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #a5a5a4;
}

.burger {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: end;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #eeeded !important;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1px);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1px);
  z-index: 9;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}

.burger i {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color: #ae0000;
}
```

Angular html code

```
<nav>
  <ul class="pushNav js-topPushNav">
    <li class="closeLevel js-closeLevelTop hdg">
      <!-- <i class="fa fa-close"></i> -->
      <i class="bi bi-x-circle"></i>
    </li>

  

      <!-- company  -->

      <li>
        <!-- Begin section 1 -->
        <div class="openLevel js-openLevel">
          <!-- <span>    <i class="bi bi-gear-wide-connected"></i></span> -->
          Services
          <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </div>

        <ul class="pushNav pushNav_level js-pushNavLevel">
          <li class="closeLevel js-closeLevel hdg">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
            Back
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="openLevel js-openLevel">
              Mobile App Development
              <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
            </div>
            <ul class="pushNav pushNav_level js-pushNavLevel">
              <li class="closeLevel js-closeLevel hdg">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
                Back
              </li>
              <li class="closetab" style="background: #ae0000">
                <a routerLink="mobile-app-development"
                  >Mobile App Development</a
                >
              </li>

              <li>
                <a routerLink="mobile-app-development/ios-application"
                  >iPhone App Development</a
                >
              </li>
              <li>
                <a routerLink="mobile-app-development/IOS-app-developmentq"
                  >Android App Development</a
                >
              </li>
              <li>
                <a routerLink="mobile-app-development/Flutter-app-development"
                  >Flutter App Development</a
                >
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="openLevel js-openLevel">
              Web Development
              <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
            </div>
            <ul class="pushNav pushNav_level js-pushNavLevel">
              <li class="closeLevel js-closeLevel hdg">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
                Back
              </li>
              <li class="closetab" style="background: #ae0000">
                <a routerLink="web-app-development">Web Development</a>
              </li>

              <li>
                <a routerLink="web-app-development/ReactJS-development"
                  >ReactJs Development</a
                >
              </li>
              <li>
                <a routerLink="web-app-development/Angular-development"
                  >Angular Development</a
                >
              </li>
              <li>
                <a routerLink="web-app-development/php-development"
                  >PHP Development</a
                >
              </li>
              <li>
                <a routerLink="web-app-development/laravel-development"
                  >Laravel Development</a
                >
              </li>
              <li>
                <a routerLink="web-app-development/NodeJS-development"
                  >NodeJs Development</a
                >
              </li>
              <li>
                <a routerLink="web-app-development/Python-Django-development">
                  Django/Python Development</a
                >
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="openLevel js-openLevel">
              Game Development
              <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
            </div>
            <ul class="pushNav pushNav_level js-pushNavLevel">
              <li class="closeLevel js-closeLevel hdg">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
                Back
              </li>
              <li class="closetab" style="background: #ae0000">
                <a routerLink="game-app-development">Game Development</a>
              </li>

              <li>
                <a routerLink="game-app-development/IOS-game-development"
                  >IOS Game Development</a
                >
              </li>
              <li>
                <a routerLink="game-app-development/Android-game-development"
                  >Android Game Development</a
                >
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="openLevel js-openLevel">
              User Experience
              <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
            </div>
            <ul class="pushNav pushNav_level js-pushNavLevel">
              <li class="closeLevel js-closeLevel hdg">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
                Back
              </li>
              <li style="background: #ae0000">
                <a routerLink="user-experience">User Experience </a>
              </li>

              <li>
                <a routerLink="user-experience/wireframe-design">Wireframe</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a routerLink="user-experience/ui-ux-design">UI/UX Design</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="openLevel js-openLevel">
              Latest Technologies
              <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
            </div>
            <ul class="pushNav pushNav_level js-pushNavLevel">
              <li class="closeLevel js-closeLevel hdg">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
                Back
              </li>
              <li class="closetab" style="background: #ae0000">
                <a routerLink="/latest-app-trends">Latest Technologies </a>
              </li>
              <li class="closetab">
                <a routerLink="/latest-app-trends/IOT-development">IOT</a>
              </li>
              <li class="closetab">
                <a routerLink="latest-app-trends/Blockchain-development"
                  >Blockchain</a
                >
              </li>
              <li class="closetab">
                <a routerLink="/latest-app-trends/augmented-virtual-Reality"
                  >AR/VR</a
                >
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

  

      <li class="">
        <a
          class="nav-link quote_btn"
          [routerLink]="'/apply'"
          routerLinkActive="active-link"
          >Get Quote</a
        >
      </li>


    </div>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

##### Hey Use this Another Method

```html
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,1px);
transform: translate3d(0,0,1px);
```

##### *TRY THIS*

Answer (score 0):

#### Z-index should be set for elements on the same level.

You should set the `z-index` on the parent's elements so that they will not be reset by their parent's z-index.

To fix your issue, you could set the z-index of `#main-wrapper` which is the parent of `.pushNav` to any number that is higher than `<app-home>`. Here's what I've tried on my device.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I made changes as per you and its working fine now. i am very thankful for this.